# What's the implementation of Vim's default 'tabline' function?

Tags: vim

In Vim, the text that forms the row of tabs at the top of the screen (when using tabs) is configured with the `tabline` option.

I'd like to make a few minor adjustments to the default tab pages line, such as replacing the number of windows in the tab with the index of the tab.  Unfortunately, the default version of this (which is active when `tabline` is unset) is complicated and undocumented.  There's nothing for me to tweak.

Is there a piece of Vim script that provides the default implementation which I could adjust to my needs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use a custom function to reset the tab number and viewport numbers, from  [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Show_tab_number_in_your_tab_line) (see Tonymec's comment). You can play with it to change how you display the tabs.

Here's what I have in my `.vimrc`. It's only a slightly modified version, that changes how the tab# and viewport# are displayed.

```vim
" Rename tabs to show tab# and # of viewports
```

```vim
if exists("+showtabline")
    function! MyTabLine()
        let s = ''
        let wn = ''
        let t = tabpagenr()
        let i = 1
        while i <= tabpagenr('$')
            let buflist = tabpagebuflist(i)
            let winnr = tabpagewinnr(i)
            let s .= '%' . i . 'T'
            let s .= (i == t ?  '%1*' : '%2*')
            let s .= ' '
            let wn = tabpagewinnr(i,'$')

            let s .= (i== t ? '%#TabNumSel#' : '%#TabNum#')
            let s .= i
            if tabpagewinnr(i,'$') > 1
                let s .= '.'
                let s .= (i== t ? '%#TabWinNumSel#' : '%#TabWinNum#')
                let s .= (tabpagewinnr(i,'$') > 1 ? wn : '')
            end

            let s .= ' %*'
            let s .= (i == t ? '%#TabLineSel#' : '%#TabLine#')
            let bufnr = buflist[winnr - 1]
            let file = bufname(bufnr)
            let buftype = getbufvar(bufnr, 'buftype')
            if buftype == 'nofile'
                if file =~ '\/.'
                    let file = substitute(file, '.*\/\ze.', '', '')
                endif
            else
                let file = fnamemodify(file, ':p:t')
            endif
            if file == ''
                let file = '[No Name]'
            endif
            let s .= file
            let s .= (i == t ?  '%m' : '')
            let i = i + 1
        endwhile
        let s .= '%T%#TabLineFill#%='
        return s
    endfunction
    set stal=2
    set tabline=%!MyTabLine()
endif
```

And here are the colors defined in my function:

```vim
set tabpagemax=15
hi TabLineSel term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=16 ctermbg=229
hi TabWinNumSel term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=90 ctermbg=229
hi TabNumSel term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=16 ctermbg=229

hi TabLine term=underline ctermfg=16 ctermbg=145
hi TabWinNum term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=90 ctermbg=145
hi TabNum term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=16 ctermbg=145
```

Comment: The only thing I can't figure out: how can I add a "+" if there's a dirty buffer?  I don't even know what to search help for to find the function... :)

Comment: @Peeja: I've modified the function above (see second line above `endwhile`), that will display a `[+]` next to the file name in an unsaved buffer _if it is the current buffer_. So, whenever you switch to a buffer and its dirty, it will display the `[+]` sign.

Comment: Yeah, that's something.  Is there not a function which takes a buffer number and returns whether it's modified?  Or, equivalently, is there a way to get a buffer-local variable for an arbitrary buffer by its number?  (I haven't been able to find one, but I'm still new to vimscripting.)

Comment: @Peeja: I think it is possible, but I haven't tried it myself. Remember that the tabline is updated at _every key stroke_. So having a function that gets info from every buffer at every keystroke can be costly really slow you down. BTW, the tabline can be written similar to the statusline and there's lot of documentation in `:help statusline` that you'll find helpful. Also look through `:help tabline`

Comment: @Peeja let bufmod = getbufvar(bufnr, '&mod') indicates if buffer # is modified.

Comment: Is there a way to show filename in the format:
`a/c/r/onym.py`

Answer (score 7):

This is not the answer you are asking for but I will share my own tabline with you.

Did it with help from [the wikia page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Show_tab_number_in_your_tab_line), here is my version.

This is where the first tab has three windows open in it, with two open on one edited file.

[image]

```vim
set showtabline=1  " 1 to show tabline only when more than one tab is present
set tabline=%!MyTabLine()  " custom tab pages line
function! MyTabLine() " acclamation to avoid conflict
    let s = '' " complete tabline goes here
    " loop through each tab page
    for t in range(tabpagenr('$'))
        " set highlight
        if t + 1 == tabpagenr()
            let s .= '%#TabLineSel#'
        else
            let s .= '%#TabLine#'
        endif
        " set the tab page number (for mouse clicks)
        let s .= '%' . (t + 1) . 'T'
        let s .= ' '
        " set page number string
        let s .= t + 1 . ' '
        " get buffer names and statuses
        let n = ''      " temp string for buffer names while we loop and check buftype
        let m = 0       " &modified counter
        let bc = len(tabpagebuflist(t + 1))     " counter to avoid last ' '
        " loop through each buffer in a tab
        for b in tabpagebuflist(t + 1)
            " buffer types: quickfix gets a [Q], help gets [H]{base fname}
            " others get 1dir/2dir/3dir/fname shortened to 1/2/3/fname
            if getbufvar( b, "&buftype"  ) == 'help'
                let n .= '[H]' . fnamemodify( bufname(b), ':t:s/.txt$//'  )
            elseif getbufvar( b, "&buftype"  ) == 'quickfix'
                let n .= '[Q]'
            else
                let n .= pathshorten(bufname(b))
            endif
            " check and ++ tab's &modified count
            if getbufvar( b, "&modified"  )
                let m += 1
            endif
            " no final ' ' added...formatting looks better done later
            if bc > 1
                let n .= ' '
            endif
            let bc -= 1
        endfor
        " add modified label [n+] where n pages in tab are modified
        if m > 0
            let s .= '[' . m . '+]'
        endif
        " select the highlighting for the buffer names
        " my default highlighting only underlines the active tab
        " buffer names.
        if t + 1 == tabpagenr()
            let s .= '%#TabLineSel#'
        else
            let s .= '%#TabLine#'
        endif
        " add buffer names
        if n == ''
            let s.= '[New]'
        else
            let s .= n
        endif
        " switch to no underlining and add final space to buffer list
        let s .= ' '
    endfor
    " after the last tab fill with TabLineFill and reset tab page nr
    let s .= '%#TabLineFill#%T'
    " right-align the label to close the current tab page
    if tabpagenr('$') > 1
        let s .= '%=%#TabLineFill#%999Xclose'
    endif
    return s
endfunction"
```

Comment: Note: (possibly also applies to most vimscript impl's of tabline) Does not help to squish/shorten the tabs when you fill the bar. This effectively limits me to 5 tabs most of the time (which is not ideal for me when stuff gets sprawled out), so i made a control to toggle between this one and the default tabline implementation.

Answer (score 5):

yoda's solution is the right one.  To specifically answer the question, there is no default value for `tabline`.  If it's not set, Vim constructs the displayed line itself.  The implementation is in `src/screen.c` at `draw_tabline()`, in the Vim 7.3 source.  I'd hoped to find a hidden default value in here that was run through the same engine, but alas it's a pure C implementation.  Makes me wonder why they didn't just construct a tabline value and use the engine to parse it, but Vim was written back in the day when CPU cycles counted, and this is certainly slightly faster.